# Python Numpy Jupyter Notebook "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()" error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, function, jupyter-notebook

[Code with Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPhyq.png)

Hi I have a question of why I'm getting this error message:

```html
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

When I'm trying to run this function, and pass in a NumPy array:

```html
testValues=np.arange(-5,5,0.01)

def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
        
factorial(testValues)
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

With numpy you are passing the entire ndarray to your function. So n isnt a single value.

Your function also doesnt make much sense. Maybe we can help you better if you tell us your ultimate goal.

If you want to apply your function to every number in `testValues`, you might want to check out numpy.vectorize

```
np.vectorize(factorial)(testValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is set up to receive an integer, not a NumPy array. Furthermore, if you are trying to calculate a factorial recursively, you are missing the recursive call to the `factorial` function.